# How to integrate Semantic-UI with Aurelia-Cli?

Tags: semantic-ui, aurelia

I want to create a custom theme with semantic-ui, but they don't have official support for Aurelia yet and a lot of unwanted errors pop up after `npm install semantic-ui --save`. I want a clear answer and aurelia.json dependency code for semantic. Thanks.

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: @LStarky Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined at aurelia-cli/lib/commands/gulp.js:72 [return original.apply(gulp, args);]

Comment: Did you try the solution below?

Comment: I'm unable to try it because au build or run stop working showing the error above after I run `npm install semantic-ui --save`, then I have to another clean install to get them working. So I'm thinking of using jspm bundler system rather than aurelia-cli

Comment: Just a tip: If you're on Windows and installing semantic-ui, you must at the time of writing use Windows CMD -- not Git-Bash. Or else you get many errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. aurelia.json dependency**

```
"dependencies": [
  ...,
  {
    "name": "semantic-ui",
    "path": "../node_modules/semantic-ui/dist",
    "main": "semantic.min.js",
    "resources": [
      "semantic.min.css"
    ]
  }
]
```

Side note: you *might* also have to list dependencies using the `"deps"` value.  Try it without this at first, and if you need to, you can see what other libraries this repo requires.

**2. Import JavaScript file**

In either `app.js` or in *each view-model* you'll be using the library, use **one** of these imports (try them one at a time; one of them is likely to work).

```
import * from 'semantic-ui';
import 'semantic-ui';
```

**3. Require CSS**

In either `app.html` or in **each view** you'll be using the library, use the following require statement.

```
<template>
  <require from="semantic-ui/semantic.min.css"></require>
  <!-- rest of your code here -->
</template>
```

**4. Legacy prepend**

If none of the above works, import it as a legacy repo using the `prepend` section of `aurelia.json` (before the `dependencies` section) like this:

```
"prepend": [
  // probably a couple other things already listed here...
  "node_modules/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.js"
],
```

Comment: For me works, but browser can't find font files. Should path to fonts be placed somewhere in config?

Answer (score 0):

**First:** If you don't need to customize Semantic UI, you can simplify by using pre-built package, downloadable as a ZIP. See Semantic UI "Getting Started" for that tip.

**This is not elegant, but it works:**

I assume you want to complete package, with build tools and everything. That gives you the option to customize, change themes, etc.

These are the problems I see:

1. Semantic UI uses Gulp 3.x, which is the official version, while Aurelia CLI uses Gulp 4, which is in alpha. This gives errors if you try to `npm install` Semantic into an Aurelia project.
2. Importing the CSS/JS files in `aurelia.json` only works with the `node_modules/semantic-ui/dist` version -- not the built `semantic/dist` version, which means your customizations don't get included.

My solution/workaround:

1. Install Semantic UI in a separate folder, e.g. `aurelia_project_root/SUI`. Solves Gulp version problem. You can now `gulp build` your Semantic distro from within that directory. Note: You need to create the folder outside of the Aurelia project, then move it inside as a sub-folder the Aurelia project root. This gives you a local version of Gulp inside the SUI/node_modules.
2. Edit `aurelia.json` to add SUI and JQuery:

   ```
     "jquery",
     {
       "name": "semantic-ui",
       "path": "../SUI/node_modules/semantic-ui/dist",
       "main": "semantic.min.js",
       "resources": [
         "semantic.min.css"
       ]
     }
   ```

To install JQuery: `npm install jquery --save`.

Edit `semantic.json` inside SUI to change the output directories to save the built files in the node_modules:

```
"output": {
  "packaged": "..\\node_modules\\semantic-ui\\dist\\",
  "uncompressed": "..\\node_modules\\semantic-ui\\dist\\components\\",
  "compressed": "..\\node_modules\\semantic-ui\\dist\\components\\",
  "themes": "..\\node_modules\\semantic-ui\\dist/themes/"
},
```

This is because of problem 2 - that Aurelia CLI only is able to import SUI as long as it is within node_modules (probably something I do wrong).

Then the workflow becomes:

1. change SUI properties
2. build SUI (`gulp build` inside SUI/semantic)
3. build/run aurelia (`au build`)

Of course, you can update your gulp tasks in aurelia to improve this workflow.

You'll also need to link or copy fonts/pngs. For now I've just symlinked it, `ln -s path-to-dist/themes themes` from you Aurelia project folder.

Your HTML:

```
<require from="semantic-ui/semantic.min.css"></require>
...
<select ref="states" class="ui fluid search dropdown" multiple="">
  <option value="">State</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
...
</select>
```

Code-behind:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery' // import $ from 'jquery';
import 'semantic-ui';

attached() {
   $(this.states).dropdown()
}
```

This should give you a very cool drop-down.